# How to insert the rows in the database mysql table in the following?

Tags: mysql

I have two table named: **Blog** for displaying blogs post and **comments** for displaying comments section for each blog post.

The fields for these are as follows:

**For Blog:**

1: blog_id

2: title

3: body

4: author

5: updated

**For Comments:**

1: comments_id

2: name

3: email

4: body

5: blog_id

The field **blog_id** must be the same for both the table.

Now what i want is that suppose for blog_id = "2", I am writing comment, so what would be the insert query so that when i visit index.php?blog_id=2, I get the comments for only that particular post.

**I mean how to insert the comments for a particular blog_id?**

I tried this query to insert:

```
INSERT INTO cms.comments(blog_id, name,email,comments_body)
                VALUES (
                    '".$arr['blog_id']."',
                    '".$arr['name']."',

                    '".$arr['email']."',
                    '".$arr['body']."'
                ) );
```

Comment: Its Like foreign key in mysql.

Comment: [What have you tried so far??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @fahim Parkar: I tried this: INSERT INTO cms.comments(comments_id, username,email,comments_body)
     VALUES (
         '".$arr['blog_id']."',
      '".$arr['username']."',
      
      '".$arr['email']."',
      '".$arr['comments_body']."'
     ) WHERE cms.comments.blog_id = '$blog_id'");

Comment: please update the same in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have done it myself [NO need to implement foreign key].

Here is the solutions.

The requirement was that the field "blog_id" of **comments** must be equal to "blog_id" of **blog**

This can be done in the following manner. First get the blog's "blog_id" by the following statement...

```
$sql = "SELECT * from blog WHERE blog_id = '$blog_id'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$iItemId = (int)$_POST['blog_id']; // obtaining necessary information
```

The using INSERT statement like this, insert it...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO amityadav.comments(blog_id, name,url,email,body)
                VALUES (
                    '$iItemId',   //This variable is from the blog_posts' "blog_id" which will be inserted into the comment's "blog_id"
                    '".$arr['name']."',
                    '".$arr['url']."',
                    '".$arr['email']."',
                    '".$arr['body']."'
                )");
```

Now in order to retrieve it use the flowing query...

```
$sql = "SELECT * from blog WHERE blog_id = '$blog_id'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$iItemId = (int)$_GET['blog_id']; // obtaining necessary information
$comments = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE `blog_id` = '{$iItemId}' ORDER BY comments.id ASC ");
```

Using these queries, I have successfully implemented what I wanted...:)

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try Foreign key in MySQL.

For More Info:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-foreign-keys.html

Comment: After going through the link, I learned about a new statement: SELECT '@last := LAST_INSERT_ID();'
Now the variable @last will need to be inserted in the other table query. But I am inserting both the values at different places

Answer (score -1):

You need to use parent child table concept with foreign keys. MySQL supports `Foreign Keys` and `cascading deletes` as part of its database storage engine.

You will need to use `InnoDB` storage engine .